# Using generics and implement optional fields in an interface or implement an interface optionally?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface

I am using `C# 6` and `.NET 4.6.2`

I make use of a generic repository and a generic `ASP.NET MVC Controller` as I have many lookup tables and don't want to create separate controllers and repositories for each

Here is my code simplified:

Models:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }

}

public class Lookup1:IEntity
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Lookup1Name { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
public class Lookup2:IEntity
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Lookup2Name { get; set; }

}
```

Repository:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    void Update(TEntity obj);
}


public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    public void  Update(TEntity obj)
    {
        table.Attach(obj);
        _db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Generic Controller:

```
 public abstract class GenericController<TModel> : Controller
    where TModel : class,IEntity
{

    private IGenericRepository<TModel> _repository;

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(TModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
                _repository.Update(model);
                await _repository.Save();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes.");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Controllers:

```
public class Lookup1Controller : GenericController<Lookup1>
{
    private IGenericRepository<Lookup1> _repository;

    public Lookup1Controller (IGenericRepository<Lookup1> repository) : base(repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}

public class Lookup2Controller : GenericController<Lookup2>
{
    private IGenericRepository<Lookup2> _repository;

    public Lookup2Controller (IGenericRepository<Lookup2> repository) : base(repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

The above works and  updates all the `Lookup1`,`Lookup2` model fields that is passed from my MVC view `.cshtml` files.

However only some of my models have the `DateCreated` and `CreatedBy` properties and I want to update these properties in the `Edit`method in my generic controller as well.

something like this

```
 model.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
 model.CreatedBy = _myService.Username;
```

However for me to do this I have to add those two properties to the interface `IEntity` but those properties only belong to some models e.g.`Lookup2` doesn't have those two properties.

The only solution I can think of is add `nullable` `DateCreated` and `CreatedBy` properties to all my model classes so I can add those properties to the `IEntity` interface and update those fields in my generic controller. However I don't think it is ideal as I have no interest in setting those properties for `Lookup2`

My Question:

1. Is it possible to have conditional properties in an interface or optionally inherit a separate conditional interface?
2. or another neater solution to my problem?

Comment: What about an `AttributeCollection` or a `Dictionary<string, object> -> PropertyName, Property`?

Comment: Otherwise you could use an `abstract class` instead of an `interface`.

Comment: Why your entities implement the interface IEntity. You do not seem to use it anywhere?Remove it and everything will work just fine

Comment: He does at this line: `public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity`

Comment: I added IEntity to demonstrate those properties need to exist in it if I want to reference it in the generic controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another interface:

```
public interface ITraceableEntity : IEntity
{
     string CreatedBy { get; set; }
     DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then implement it on the concrete classes that you want:

```
public class Lookup1 : ITraceableEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Lookup1Name { get; set; }

     public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

     public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

On the generic controller you can check if the instance is implementing this interface and then cast it:

```
try
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
        if (model is ITraceableEntity)
        {
           ((ITraceableEntity)model).CreatedBy = _myService.Username;  // <---
           ((ITraceableEntity)model).CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;       // <---
        }
        _repository.Update(model);
        await _repository.Save();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes.");
}
return View(model);
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code seems to work without the controller having to implement the `ITraceableEntity` interface so I don't need to add it to the line `where TModel : class,IEntity`